# Performance implication of emitting `onCompleted()` or not

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-android

I've got something like this.

```
Button button = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH);
PublishSubject<Event> subject = PublishSubject.create();
button.addListener(SWT.Selection, e -> subject.onNext(e));
subject.subscribe(e -> System.out.println("selection=" + e));
```

As you can see, `onCompleted()` never gets emitted.  If I make a bunch of these and lose my handle to them, they get garbage-collected just fine.

I'm deciding if I should add this line:

```
button.addListener(SWT.Dispose, e -> subject.onCompleted());
```

As best I can tell, this just adds yet another anonymous class that needs to be GC'ed, which seems like a bad deal.  Am I thinking about this right?  Any advantages to emitting `onCompleted()` that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any advantages to calling `onCompleted` in this case. If your observable used some resource that needed disposing of once you'd finished with the observable then I would say you should pass in a terminating event or unsubscribe.

If you wanted to be safe in these cases generally I would unsubscribe from the `Subscriber` instance that you subscribed with (create one and hold a reference to it so you can call `subscriber.unsubscribe()`).

Comment: Thanks for the input Dave :)